# Values on Y-axis disappear (hide under labels)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, chart.js

I use ChartJS library to create line chart. Somehow, the value on the Y values are almost hidden. 
I am wondering if I have set of data, how can I dynamically make y value so that it won't hide my y-value and still automatically scale base on my dataset selection.

And here is the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JORPbJ)

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: [1510001367000, 1510001379000, 1510001415000, 1510001427000],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'dataset 1',
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: [72, 72, 72, 72]
          },
          {
            label: 'dataset 2',
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
            data: [70, 70, 70, 70]
          }
        ]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true      
    }
});
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  width: 600px;
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="myChartDiv">
      <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="800"></canvas>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thank you for the codepen, always helps to have these in a question!

You can set the min/max of the yAxis by adding the following scale options:

```
options: {
      responsive: true,
      scales:{
        yAxes:[{
          ticks:{
            suggestedMin:69,
            suggestedMax:73
          }
        }]
      }
    }
```

here is a forked [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JORjNe)

> [relevant docs here](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#axis-range-settings)

You can always calculate the min and max as (min - 1) and (max +1) respectively to always get have an offset of 1.

**UPDATE: =================================**

In you're CodePen, you are using Chartjs 2.1.3, which is now an old version. Here is how you can build a simple plugin to add an offset to the linear char min/max:

first the plugin:

```
// Define a plugin to provide data labels
Chart.pluginService.register({
  beforeUpdate: function(chart) {
    // get custom defined offset
    var offset = chart.options.customOffset;
    // exisit gracefully if offset not defined or less than 0
    if(!offset || offset < 0) return;

    // preset the min and max
    var max = Number.MIN_VALUE;
    var min = Number.MAX_VALUE;

    // find min/max values of all datasets
    chart.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset){
      var newMax = Math.max.apply(null, dataset.data);
      var newMin = Math.min.apply(null, dataset.data); 
      max = newMax > max ? newMax : max;
      min = newMin > min ? min : newMin;
    });
    // change min and max tick values
    chart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.max = max + offset;
    chart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.min = min - offset;
  }
});
```

now you can add a `customOffset` property to options:

```
 options: {
      customOffset: 0.1,
      responsive: true,
    }
```

Take a look at this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JORjNe)

sample preview with 0.5 offset with your data:
[image]

**UPDATE 2 =========================**

Small changes to plugin so that when one dataset is hidden, the others are centered and the chart behave appropriately:

```
Chart.pluginService.register({
  beforeUpdate: function(chart){
    console.log("beforeUpdate");
    // get custom defined offset
    var offset = chart.options.customOffset;
    // exisit gracefully if offset not defined or less than 0
    if(!offset || offset < 0) return;

    // preset the min and max
    var max = Number.MIN_VALUE;
    var min = Number.MAX_VALUE;

    // find min/max values of all dataset
    chart.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset){
      if(!dataset._meta[0].hidden){
        console.log(dataset)
        var newMax = Math.max.apply(null, dataset.data);
        var newMin = Math.min.apply(null, dataset.data); 
        max = newMax > max ? newMax : max;
        min = newMin > min ? min : newMin;
      }
    });
    // change min and max tick values
    chart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.max = max + offset;
    chart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.min = min - offset;
  }
});
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NwREOd?editors=0010)

**UPDATE 3 =========================**

here is a plugin to add offset to ALL Y Axes in the chart:

```
Chart.pluginService.register({
    beforeUpdate: function(chart){
      console.log("beforeUpdate");
      // get custom defined offset
      var offset = chart.options.customOffset;
      // exisit gracefully if offset not defined or less than 0
      if(!offset || offset < 0) return;
      var yAxes = chart.options.scales.yAxes;
      for(var i=0; i<yAxes.length; i++){
        var axis = yAxes[i];
        var datasets = chart.data.datasets;
        var max = Number.MIN_VALUE;
        var min = Number.MAX_VALUE;
        var datasetsOnAxis = [];

        for(var j=0; j<datasets.length; j++){ // add datasets for this axes to datasetsOnAxis
          var dataset = datasets[j];
          var meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(j);
          if  (meta.yAxisID === axis.id) datasetsOnAxis.push(dataset); 
        }

        for(var k=0; k<datasetsOnAxis.length; k++){
          var dataset = datasetsOnAxis[k]
          var newMax = Math.max.apply(null, dataset.data);
          var newMin = Math.min.apply(null, dataset.data);
          max = newMax > max ? newMax : max;
          min = newMin > min ? min : newMin;
        }
        axis.ticks.max = max + offset;
        axis.ticks.min = min - offset;   
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: if I set min/max for those, the chart won't autoscale if I turn either one on/off. The scale is always at min/max. What if I have more than 2 datasets, and the other datasets have very small values, then the Y-axis is not autoscale when I turn off the big datasets.

Comment: For example, codepen.io/anon/pen/KygeRw here is the codepen. If I take off dataset 1 and dataset 2 from the chart by clicking on the dataset 1 and dataset 2 legends. Then the dataset 3 will show very low on the chart. Anyway to make the y autoscale if the dataset 1 and dataset 2 are hidden in this case?

Comment: Updated the answer with a dynamic plugin so you dont have to hardcode the min/max

Comment: Thanks. but what happens when user click onto any of dataset legend to hide one of them. it will either stay very low in the graph and high in the graph instead of trying to center in the middle. (Without but max and min on the option, the y-axis will autoscale base on which dataset is not hidden.

Comment: Updated my answer so that now chart lines get centered when one is hiddden.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at ChartPlugin.js:15

Comment: It gave me error at the line: if(!dataset._meta[0].hidden)

Comment: I forked the codepen you provided, in my answer I added a codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NwREOd?editors=0010 which works just fine for me.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to find why I can't read _meta by using console.log(data._meta) on your script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158452/discussion-between-ahmed-musallam-and-tenz).

Comment: @Ahmend does there a way to hide the customOffset number on the y-axis?