# Chart JS, Choose different Y-axis for different datasets

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a multiple Y axis on my chart [Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gXmGwm). I am wondering if user can choose which dataset he/she want on which y-axis? 
Is there a way to show which data is currently using which Y-axis, and users haveoption to change the data to different axis (left or right) if they like on the legend?

```js
Chart.defaults.global.elements.line.fill = false;

  var barChartData = {
  labels: [1510332261000, 1510332473000, 1510332489000, 1510332726000, 1510332777000, 1510332778000, 1510332958000, 1510333050000, 1510333131000, 1510333389000, 1510333476000, 1510333493000, 1510333588000, 1510333604000, 1510333664000, 1510333668000, 1510333758000, 1510333801000, 1510333820000, 1510333821000, 1510333878000, 1510333928000],
  datasets: [{
  type: 'line',
  label: 'a (F)',
  id: "y-axis-0",
  backgroundColor: "rgba(217,83,79,0.75)",
  data: [70, 72, 73, 73, 75, 50, 50, 40, 40, 45, 70, 73, 70, 73, 73, 73, 74, 73, 73, 73]
}, {
  type: 'line',
  label: 'b (V)',
  id: "y-axis-0",
  backgroundColor: "rgba(92,184,92,0.75)",
  data: [12.9, 17.9, 15.9, 17.9, 17.9, 17.9, 15.9, 17.9, 15.8, 17.8, 16.8, 17.8, 17.9, 17.9, 17.8, 17.8, 19.8, 17.9, 17.8, 20.8]
}, {
  type: 'line',
  label: 'c (%)',
  id: "y-axis-0",
  backgroundColor: "rgba(51,51,51,0.5)",
  data: [30, 30, 50, 30, 20, 10, 30, 40, 30, 50, 30, 70, 30, 50, 30, 80, 90, 30, 30, 30]
}, {
  type: 'line',
  label: 'd (AH)',
  id: "y-axis-1",
  backgroundColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
  data: [10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6]
  }]
};


var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
// allocate and initialize a chart
var ch = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: barChartData,
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: "Chart.js"
    },
    tooltips: {
       mode: 'label'
    },
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        position: "left",
        id: "y-axis-0",
      }, {
        position: "right",
        id: "y-axis-1",
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="myChartDiv">
      <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

**Update**

I customized the legend as [this](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2565), and use   [Ahmed 's suggestion code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47146427/values-on-y-axis-disappear-hide-under-labels/47146782) to fix Y-axis scale. I also added [Ahmed's y axis code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ooZMwG?editors=0010) to the update, but somehow, it still doesn't work as I expect. 
Here is the [new codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zPzqQQ) that I just updated

Comment: wouldn't that be confusing? the y-axis should be the same to keep the same scale for all your datasets. the value labels may be different but on the same scale. It would be confusing if your datasets do not have the same `scale`. If your datasets use different scales, you have to create a new chart. Are there any examples/use-cases of charts that use different scale on different axes?

Comment: Update the codepen. I had different scales on different dataset. I just want people able to select which dataset they want on which axis. Starting at all in 1 axis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fist of all in your `barChartData.datasets[]` you are using `id` but you should use `yAxisID`instead. giving `id` there has no impact on the chart. here is the doc for that: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#dataset-properties

Now onto what you're asking, you can add a click handler to the legend to toggle between axes on click, here is an example of that:

> a fork codepen off of yours with new code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ooZMwG?editors=0010

set `options.legend.onClick` to this function:

```
function(e, legendItem) {
    var index = legendItem.datasetIndex;
    var ci = this.chart;

    var axisIds = []
    var yAxes = ci.options.scales.yAxes;
    for (var i = 0; i < yAxes.length; i++) { // loop over the registered yAxes
        yAxes[i].gridLines.color = "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)"; // reset all scale gridlines to default
        axisIds.push(yAxes[i].id) // get all yAxes ids
    }

    var meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(index);
    var currentAxisId = meta.yAxisID
    var currentAxisIdIndex = axisIds.indexOf(currentAxisId);
    var newAxisIdIndex;
    // basically get the next axis id in the array, if the last one, get the first (circular)
    if (currentAxisIdIndex == axisIds.length - 1) newAxisIdIndex = 0;
    else newAxisIdIndex = currentAxisIdIndex + 1;

    var newAxisId = axisIds[newAxisIdIndex];
    meta.yAxisID = newAxisId // set the new axis id to the next one in the array

    axis = ci.scales[newAxisId];
    axis.options.gridLines.color = "rgba(0,0,0,1)"; // change lines color of the new axes 
    ci.update(); // update chart
}
```

**UPDATE: **

based on your new codepen, here are a few things to help:

I have added a new update to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47146427/values-on-y-axis-disappear-hide-under-labels/47146782)  to add offfset to all Y Axes in the chart. Use that instead of what you have in the pen.

then update your `changeLeftRightY` to the following and make sure your legend HTML container has the id: `legend`

```
changeLeftRightY = function(e, index) {
            //console.log("-- " + data.datasets[index].yAxisID)
            var ci = e.view.ch;
            var axisIds = []
            var yAxes = ci.options.scales.yAxes;
            for (var i = 0; i < yAxes.length; i++) { // loop over the registered yAxes
                yAxes[i].gridLines.color = "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)"; // reset all scale gridlines to default
                axisIds.push(yAxes[i].id) // get all yAxes ids
            }
            var meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(index);
            var currentAxisId = meta.yAxisID
            var currentAxisIdIndex = axisIds.indexOf(currentAxisId);
            var newAxisIdIndex;
            // basically get the next axis id in the array, if the last one, get the first (circular)
            if (currentAxisIdIndex == axisIds.length - 1) newAxisIdIndex = 0;
            else newAxisIdIndex = currentAxisIdIndex + 1;

            var newAxisId = axisIds[newAxisIdIndex];
            meta.yAxisID = newAxisId // set the new axis id to the next one in the array

            axis = ci.scales[newAxisId];
            axis.options.gridLines.color = "rgba(0,0,0,1)"; // change lines color of the new axes
            document.getElementById('legend').innerHTML = ci.generateLegend();

            ci.update()
        }
```

Here is a [codepen with the code result](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KyqaGj?editors=0010) *I have made some changes to some of your code to make it easier to read.

*If that codepen is changed or deleted, here is the full code*

```
// set default no fill beneath the line
Chart.defaults.global.elements.line.fill = false;
// Define a plugin to provide data labels
Chart.pluginService.register({
    beforeUpdate: function(chart){
      console.log("beforeUpdate");
      // get custom defined offset
      var offset = chart.options.customOffset;
      // exisit gracefully if offset not defined or less than 0
      if(!offset || offset < 0) return;
      var yAxes = chart.options.scales.yAxes;
      for(var i=0; i<yAxes.length; i++){
        var axis = yAxes[i];
        var datasets = chart.data.datasets;
        var max = Number.MIN_VALUE;
        var min = Number.MAX_VALUE;
        var datasetsOnAxis = [];

        for(var j=0; j<datasets.length; j++){ // add datasets for this axes to datasetsOnAxis
          var dataset = datasets[j];
          var meta = chart.getDatasetMeta(j);
          if  (meta.yAxisID === axis.id) datasetsOnAxis.push(dataset); 
        }

        for(var k=0; k<datasetsOnAxis.length; k++){
          var dataset = datasetsOnAxis[k]
          var newMax = Math.max.apply(null, dataset.data);
          var newMin = Math.min.apply(null, dataset.data);
          max = newMax > max ? newMax : max;
          min = newMin > min ? min : newMin;
        }
        axis.ticks.max = max + offset;
        axis.ticks.min = min - offset;   
      }
    }
});

var barChartData = {
  labels: [1510332261000, 1510332473000, 1510332489000, 1510332726000, 1510332777000, 1510332778000, 1510332958000, 1510333050000, 1510333131000, 1510333389000, 1510333476000, 1510333493000, 1510333588000, 1510333604000, 1510333664000, 1510333668000, 1510333758000, 1510333801000, 1510333820000, 1510333821000, 1510333878000, 1510333928000],
  datasets: [{
    type: 'line',
    label: 'a (F)',
    yAxisID: "y-axis-0",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(217,83,79,0.75)",
    data: [70, 72, 73, 73, 75, 50, 50, 40, 40, 45, 70, 73, 70, 73, 73, 73, 74, 73, 73, 73]
  }, {
    type: 'line',
    label: 'b (V)',
    yAxisID: "y-axis-0",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(92,184,92,0.75)",
    data: [12.9, 17.9, 15.9, 17.9, 17.9, 17.9, 15.9, 17.9, 15.8, 17.8, 16.8, 17.8, 17.9, 17.9, 17.8, 17.8, 19.8, 17.9, 17.8, 20.8]
  }, {
    type: 'line',
    label: 'c (%)',
    yAxisID: "y-axis-0",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(51,51,51,0.5)",
    data: [30, 30, 50, 30, 20, 10, 30, 40, 30, 50, 30, 70, 30, 50, 30, 80, 90, 30, 30, 30]
  }, {
    type: 'line',
    label: 'd (AH)',
    yAxisID: "y-axis-1",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
    data: [10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6, 10.6]
  }]
};

var options = {
  title: {
      display: true,
      text: "Chart.js"
    },
  legendCallback: function (chart) {
                console.log('legendCallback');
                var legendHtml = [];
                legendHtml.push('<div id="legend">');
                for (var i = 0; i < chart.data.datasets.length; i++) {
                    var meta = ch.getDatasetMeta(i);
                    var yAxis = meta.yAxisID =='y-axis-0' ? "Left Axis" : "Right Axis"

                    if (chart.data.datasets[i].label) {
                        var datasetIndex = chart.legend.legendItems[i].datasetIndex
                        var color = chart.data.datasets[i].backgroundColor;
                        var label = chart.data.datasets[i].label;
                        legendHtml.push(
                          '<div class="lgnd-item-container">'+
                            '<input class="lgnd-ckeckbox" type="checkbox" checked '+
                                    'onclick="updateDataset(event, '+datasetIndex+')"/>'+
                            '<div class="lgnd-square" style="background-color:'+color+'"></div>'+
                            '<div class="lgnd-label">'+label+' '+yAxis+'</div>'+
                            '<input class="lgnd-btn" type="button" value="Change" onclick="changeLeftRightY(event,'+datasetIndex +')"></input>'+
                          '</div>');
                    }
                }
                legendHtml.push('</div>');

                return legendHtml.join("");
            },
            legend:{
              display:false
            },
            customOffset: 2,
            responsive: true,
            tooltips: {
                mode: 'label',
                position: 'nearest'
            },
  scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        position: "left",
        id: "y-axis-0",
      }, {
        position: "right",
        id: "y-axis-1",
      }]
    }

}

// Show/hide chart by click legend
updateDataset = function (e, datasetIndex) {
            var index = datasetIndex;
            var ci = e.view.ch;
            var meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(index);
            // See controller.isDatasetVisible comment
            meta.hidden = meta.hidden === null ? !ci.data.datasets[index].hidden : null;
            // We hid a dataset ... rerender the chart
            ci.update();
        };

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
// allocate and initialize a chart
window.ch = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: barChartData,
  options: options

});
document.getElementById("chartLegend").innerHTML = ch.generateLegend();

changeLeftRightY = function(e, index) {
            //console.log("-- " + data.datasets[index].yAxisID)
            var ci = e.view.ch;
            var axisIds = []
            var yAxes = ci.options.scales.yAxes;
            for (var i = 0; i < yAxes.length; i++) { // loop over the registered yAxes
                yAxes[i].gridLines.color = "rgba(0,0,0,0.1)"; // reset all scale gridlines to default
                axisIds.push(yAxes[i].id) // get all yAxes ids
            }
            var meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(index);
            var currentAxisId = meta.yAxisID
            var currentAxisIdIndex = axisIds.indexOf(currentAxisId);
            var newAxisIdIndex;
            // basically get the next axis id in the array, if the last one, get the first (circular)
            if (currentAxisIdIndex == axisIds.length - 1) newAxisIdIndex = 0;
            else newAxisIdIndex = currentAxisIdIndex + 1;

            var newAxisId = axisIds[newAxisIdIndex];
            meta.yAxisID = newAxisId // set the new axis id to the next one in the array

            axis = ci.scales[newAxisId];
            axis.options.gridLines.color = "rgba(0,0,0,1)"; // change lines color of the new axes
            document.getElementById('legend').innerHTML = ci.generateLegend();

            ci.update()
        }
```

CSS:

```
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
.lgnd-square {
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  width:20px;
  overflow:hidden; 
  margin: 5px;
}

.lgnd-ckeckbox{
  float:left;
  margin: 10px;
}
.lgnd-btn{
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
.lgnd-item-container{
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
}
.lgnd-label{
  float:left;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="myChartDiv">
      <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div id="chartLegend"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your support. I did a little twist and this is what I have https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zPzqQQ I still can't get it changes the a-xis and update its axis label

Comment: Can you please make an update to your question with the new changes you made. Then I can take a look and help you from there.

Comment: I just did, I used one of your previous helped in this too.

Comment: updated the answer, here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KyqaGj?editors=0010

Comment: Thank you so much :) you are awesome. I think I have what I need for now

Comment: One quick question, why I removed class="lgnd-item-container" or add make lgnd-item-container {float:left}. The chart acts so weird https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KyvpZv. Most of the data was gone

Comment: The strange behavior has nothing to do with the class, in your case, you want to use `afterUpdate` instead of `beforeUpdate`.

Comment: When i change to afterUpdate, the customOffset in your plugin doesnt work anymore

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JOyYNd here you go, the afterUpdate. one of the point is beyond max

Comment: and if I change a(F) to right a-xis, the data dissapear

Comment: add `chart.update();` before return of `legendCallback`, see this pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aVyddB?editors=0010

Comment: Is there a way to hide one y axis if all data is on other axis? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yPoOXz?editors=0010 the number 1.7976... is kind use up a lot of space. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158991/discussion-between-ahmed-musallam-and-tenz).

Comment: Somehow the auto offset doesnt work anymore. When you uncheck a box, it doesnt auto scale the Y-axis anymore. Any suggestion? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KyqaGj?editors=0010